# error: cannot find symbol variable MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey Android

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android.I need help to solve the error below.
Got stuck here.

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("94043");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
        mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
         * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
         */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }
            return resultStrs;

        }
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
                final String APPID_PARAM = "02867cfd75153da1eda43a17f213ffc5";


                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY)

                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast string: " + forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
            return null;
        }


            }
        }
    }
}

[{
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.example.patels.sunshine";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey;
}
```

[image]

I have written this code....I got stuck here..Unable to solve the error.
Help me out....Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Under the app folder you can find `build.gradle` file, in this make this below changes.

Since you are using a String you have to use this syntax:

```
it.buildConfigField "String" , "OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY" ,  "\"MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey\""
```

The last parameter has to be a String.

Comment: thank you, silly! how are we supposed to know this when the Udacity course is barley starting

Answer (score 0):

You should create an account here http://openweathermap.org/ and when you register with your email, you get an APIKey for your account. Use this api key  and replace the MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey in the following line:

```
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey;
```

Another alternative would be to write the APIKey in grandle file as proposed already.